# How to quickly estimate file sizes of resized images on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, cocoa-touch, image-processing

In Mail, when I add an image and try to send it, it quickly asks me which size I want to send the images as. See screenshot:

[image]

I want to do something similar in an app where I will be uploading an image and want to enable the user to resize the image before it is uploaded. What is the best way to estimate the file size as Apple does here?

It seems that it would take too long to actually create each of the resized images only to check them for sizes. Is there a better way?

I did find [this Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which helps a little bit but to be honest is a bit overwhelming. :)

Comment: Is the screenshot from a panoramic image? That might throw the

Comment: Are you sure that's an estimate and not a contract? So it's not saying 'medium would be X by Y; let's say we can do that in 1.1 mb and if the user selects that we'll experiment with compression quality when they click send until we get 1.1 mb'?

Comment: I'm not sure, no - but the actual file size is later VERY close but not equal to the estimates(?) I see in that dialog.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The single biggest factor in determining the final compressed image size is not image size or JPEG compression quality, but image complexity (lit. entropy). If you know that you're always going to be dealing with highly-detailed photos (as opposed to solid color fields or gradients), that somewhat reduces the variance along that dimension, but...

I spent a fair amount of time doing numerical analysis on this problem. I sampled the compressed image size of a detailed, high-resolution image that was scaled down in 10 percentage point increments, at 9 different JPEG quality levels. This produced a 3-dimensional data set describing an implicit function z = (x, y) where x is the scaled image size in pixels (w*h), y is the JPEG compression quality, and z is the size of the resulting image in bytes.

The resulting surface is hard to estimate. Counterintuitively, it has oscillations and multiple inflection points, meaning that a function of degree 2 in both x and y is insufficient to fit it, and increasing the polynomial degrees and creating custom fitting functions didn't yield significantly better results. Not only is it not a linear relation, it isn't even a monotonic relation. It's just complex.

Let's get practical. Notice when Apple prompts you for the image size: when you hit "Send", not when the image first appears in the mail composition view. This gives them as long as it takes to compose your message before they have to have the estimated image sizes ready. So my suspicion is this: **they do it the hard way**. Scaling the image to the different sizes can be parallelized and performed in the background, and even though it takes several seconds on iPhone 4-calibur hardware, all of that work can be hidden from the user. If you're concerned about memory usage, you can write the images to temporary files and render them sequentially instead of in parallel, which will use no more than ~2x the memory of the uncompressed file in memory.

In summary: unless you know a lot about the expected entropy of the images you're compressing, any estimation function will be wildly inaccurate for some class of images. If you can handle that, then it's fairly easy to do a linear or quadratic fit on some sample data and produce a function for estimation purposes. However, if you want to get as close as Apple does, you probably need to do the actual resizing work in the background, since there are simply too many factors to construct a heuristic that gets it right all of the time.

Comment: this is what we suspected as well, but you definitely back it up with more than just a "gut feeling", thanks. Unless someone else comes up with a solution, I will be accepting this answer and awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a method that would resize the image, like so:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(CGFloat)resizedWidth height:(CGFloat)resizedHeight
{
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, 8, 4 * resizedWidth, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;
}
```

And to get the size of the image, you would have to convert it into `NSData`, and ask for the length:

```
 UIImage* actualImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

NSData* actualImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(actualImage);

NSLog(@"Actual %f KB", (CGFloat)actualImageData.length / (CGFloat)1024);


UIImage* largeImage = [self resizeImage:actualImage width:actualImage.size.width * 0.8 height:actualImage.size.height * 0.8];

NSData* largeImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(largeImage);

NSLog(@"Large %f KB", (CGFloat)largeImageData.length / (CGFloat)1024);


UIImage* mediumImage = [self resizeImage:actualImage width:actualImage.size.width * 0.5 height:actualImage.size.height * 0.5];

NSData* mediumImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mediumImage);

NSLog(@"Medium %f KB", (CGFloat)mediumImageData.length / (CGFloat)1024);


UIImage* smallImage = [self resizeImage:actualImage width:actualImage.size.width * 0.3 height:actualImage.size.height * 0.3];

NSData* smallImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);

NSLog(@"Small %f KB", (CGFloat)smallImageData.length / (CGFloat)1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store it to `NSData` you can call `[NSData length]` to get number of bytes contained and then divide it to get proper sizes in kB or MB

Comment: This does not take a compression with JPG into account.

Answer (score 0):

The image sizes provided in the Mail app are only estimates - the actual filesize of the sent image is different. It would be also be far too slow to convert a full-size image (3264 x 2448 in the iPhone 4S) to the various sizes, just to get the filesize.

[edit]

The compression filesizes aren't linear, so you can't just get numPixels/filesize to accurately estimate the filesize for smaller images.

So this answer isn't totally useless, here are the image sizes the Mail.app exports at:

Small: 320x240
Medium: 640x480
Large: 1224x1632

Comment: doesn't seem correct since as you can see in the screenshot, "Large" is over 1MB while "Medium" is 46KB - even though it's only a fourth of the image size. Seems to be taking compression into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to compress an image. The four options can be values ranging 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.0 whose size can be found out easily by calculations on image after applying the same method.