# Swift 3 - Can't upload image to Parse size exceed 10 megs

Tags: swift, image, parse-server

```
let taskToPost = PFObject(className:"TasksTest2")

 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageTest.image!)
                let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image1.png", data: imageData!)
                taskToPost["imageFile"] = imageFile
```

I use the simulator ( and the default images in the simulator library) to upload text and images to Parse, the text works fine but I keep getting an error for the image.  Says that the image is above 10 megs.  How can i resize the image to under 10 megs ?

Comment: If it has to be PNG you would need to scale the image, if you can upload jpg you can adjust the compression

Comment: And how would i do that ? Sorry i'm a newbie :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi/29726675#29726675

Comment: If you need to scale the pixels of your PNG http://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/2303865

Comment: if you are using parse-server you can define max size of an object... it is in index.js file on server