# xcode: uploaded images to firebase storage are gaining file size

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

Im when im uploading images to firebase storage after selecting a image via camera or gallery my file size is massive (10-20mb). When i view it on the device on through the computer its only 1-2mb. I cant figure out how or why the extra file size is being created.

here is my code for uploading the image to firebase

```
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let StorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Quads").child(imageName)

    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView1.image!){

        StorageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:{
            (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("could not upload image")
            } else {
                print("saved photo successfully")

                if let image1URL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                    self.datatodb(image1URL: image1URL, imageName: imageName)
                }

            }
        })

    }
```

Editing: Fixed the issue by changing UIImagePNGRepresentation to UIImageJPEGRepresentation and using the compression value to alter size.

Comment: Can you try compressing the image as specified here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi

Comment: I changed it from a pngRepresentation to the jpeg one and put .25 as the compression and its worked perfectly thank you. :)

Comment: No worries ....