# How to reduce image bit-depth (Quantization) with Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiimage, quantization, bit-depth

is there a way on iPhone to reduce image bit-depth.
I'm trying to reduce the image size to less than 1 MB but I don't want change the image width and height. so reducing the image resolution might be the correct way to do that. Anyone know how to do that using swift?

Comment: Please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726675/3420996

Comment: This example is using JPEG but I need to do that with PNG image so I do not lose transparency area

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?