# Set limit on file size before uploading it on the server in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, assets

I am uploading Media(Image, Video, Audio) from local iPhone photo library. Now, the problem is that the files are too big in size. Is there any way to set following limitations on the file to be uploaded
1. Maximum file size limit is 2MB.
2. Reduce file size to 2MB if its larger than 2MB.
3. If the file size is smaller than 2MB just upload as it is.

Comment: For image yes, that's possible, and can be quickly done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi/29726675
For Video & Audio, it might be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

**For Image/Video** you can get the size using this code in bytes

asset is the object of ALAsset

```
asset.defaultRepresentation().size()
```

**For Audio** you can try this

Get `media:MPMediaItem` from `MPMediaPickerController`

```
    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + (media.title!)) as URL!

    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: (media.assetURL!))

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exportSession?.outputURL = fileUrl
    exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp3
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {

        if exportSession?.status == .completed {

            do {
                let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileUrl!)
                do { try data.write(to: fileUrl! as URL)
                    let size = data.count // in bytes
                } catch { print("something wrong.")}

            } catch {
                print("Something went worng.", exportSession?.status as Any)
            }
        } else {
            print("Something went worng.", exportSession?.status as Any)
        }
    }
```