# Reduce the file size of png image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image, ios-stickers

How can I reduce the file size of png image to less than 64KB and without losing the transparent background and maintain 512 X 512 pixels in Swift.

I have tried this code:

```
   func resizeImageOriginalSize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var actualHeight: Float = Float(self.size.height)
    var actualWidth: Float = Float(self.size.width)
    let maxHeight: Float = Float(targetSize.height)
    let maxWidth: Float = Float(targetSize.width)
    var imgRatio: Float = actualWidth / actualHeight
    let maxRatio: Float = maxWidth / maxHeight
    var compressionQuality: Float = 0.5
    //50 percent compression

    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        }
        else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
        else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            compressionQuality = 0.4
        }
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(actualWidth), height: CGFloat(actualHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, CGFloat(compressionQuality))
    self.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()



    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

but size is not what I expected.

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: That mostly depends on the number of colors in the image and how easily it can be compressed.

Comment: Have you tried scaling the image?

Comment: @PratyushPratikI have tried scaling, but it does not reduce the file size much, I want to be less than 64KB

Comment: There is a website [https://tinypng.com] they managed to do it will.

Comment: @dev what is ur image filesize?

Comment: @dev, if you tell more about the purpose of size reduction and the reason of 64KB restriction, you will more likely receive help.

Comment: @PratyushPratik  image filesize that I'm trying with is 469KB, but whatever size I give I want to reduce to appropriately 64kb

Comment: @fewlinesofcode I'm trying to make WhatsApp sticker pack, its alow only 512X512 pixels and file size should be less than 100kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm compressing to WebP formate which providing around 3X smaller file sizes compared to PNG as I'm to create WhatsApp sticker pack, which also accepts WebP

Answer (score 2):

You should check [WWDC Session 219 - Image and graphics best practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/). First third of it contains useful information on how to optimize graphics, particularly memory footprint.

One of the ways proposed is the Downsampling technique. Here is a snippet:

```
func downsample(imageAt imageURL: URL, to pointSize: CGSize, scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, imageSourceOptions)!
    let maxDimensionInPixels = max(pointSize.width, pointSize.height) * scale
    let downsampleOptions =
            [kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxDimensionInPixels] as CFDictionary
    let downsampledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions)!
    return UIImage(cgImage: downsampledImage)
}
```

Downsampling will reduce image memory size proportionally to the downsampled size change. Further there is always a tradeoff between image quality and memory footprint and the result highly depends on compression algorithm and compression settings.

This [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi), and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293258/7388630) provides some tips.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I decrease the number of colors in the image and keep the same 512 X 512 pixels output which is the same as the input size?

Comment: @dev, roughly the idea is: You select a pixel and repaint surrounding pixels with colors, which a similar, to the color of the pixel. The best case, if human eye cannot see the difference. In practice it is very hard to do. For your case, you should use minimum colors in your images and, which is more important - no or minimum gradients. Vector-like illustrations with few colors fit 512x512 / 100KB for sure, therefore for the photos you will have to compress png and the quality will not be "crisp". c'est la vie